# Why does explicit return make a difference in a Proc?

Tags: ruby, return, proc-object

```
def foo
  f = Proc.new { return "return from foo from inside proc" }
  f.call # control leaves foo here
  return "return from foo" 
end

def bar
  b = Proc.new { "return from bar from inside proc" }
  b.call # control leaves bar here
  return "return from bar" 
end

puts foo # prints "return from foo from inside proc" 
puts bar # prints "return from bar"
```

I thought the `return` keyword was optional in Ruby and that you are always `return`ing whether you request it or not. Given that, I find it surprising that `foo` and `bar` have different output determined by the fact that `foo` contains an explicit `return` in `Proc f`.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Ruby has three constructs:

1. A *block* is not an object and is created by `{` ... `}` or `do` ... `end`.
2. A *proc* is a `Proc` object created by `Proc.new` or `proc`.
3. A *lambda* is a `Proc` created by `lambda` (or `proc` in Ruby 1.8).

Ruby has three keywords that return from something:

1. `return` terminates the method or lambda it is in.
2. `next` terminates the block, proc, or lambda it is in.
3. `break` terminates the method that yielded to the block or invoked the proc or lambda it is in.

In lambdas, `return` behaves like `next`, for whatever reason. `next` and `break` are named the way they are because they are most commonly used with methods like `each`, where terminating the block will cause the iteration to resume with the **next** element of the collection, and terminating `each` will cause you to **break** out of the loop.

---

If you use `return` inside the definition of `foo`, you will return from `foo`, even if it is inside a block or a proc. To return from a block, you can use the `next` keyword instead.

```
def foo
  f = Proc.new { next "return from foo from inside proc" }
  f.call # control leaves foo here
  return "return from foo" 
end
puts foo # prints "return from foo"
```

Comment: Edited to also mention the behaviour of lambdas

Comment: note, in your example if next is omitted, the behavior remains.

Comment: btw, I think we both did a great job answering a different question :) as to why, I think only Matz knows, a lot of the stuff around closures violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer here.  Really clears things up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with nice example

Answer (score 16):

This is the semantics for `Proc`s; it is not necessarily the semantics for all blocks. I agree this is a bit confusing. It is there for added flexibility (and perhaps partially cause Ruby has no spec except for its implementation).

The behavior is defined in the `Proc` implementation. `Lambda`s behave differently, so if you would like your `return`s **not to exit** out of the enclosing method, use **lambdas**. Or, omit the `return` keyword from your `Proc`.

A deep investigation of Rubys closures [is here](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb). It is a fantastic exposé.

So:

```
def foo   
  f = Proc.new {
    p2 = Proc.new { return "inner proc"};
    p2.call
    return "proc"
  }
  f.call
  return "foo"
end

def foo2
  result = Proc.new{"proc"}.call
  "foo2 (proc result is: #{result})"
end

def bar
  l = lambda { return "lambda" }
  result = l.call
  return "bar (lambda result is: #{result})"
end

puts foo
# inner proc
puts foo2
# foo (proc result is: proc) 
puts bar
# bar (lambda result is: lambda)
```

Comment: "This is the semantics for Procs, it is not necessarily the semantics for all blocks." It is the semantics for Proc instances created by Proc.new as well as all "normal" blocks (i.e. blocks that aren't used together with the `proc` or `lambda` keywords).

Comment: True, I could add an example, but I think my example is complicated enough as it.

Comment: for some reason lambdas converted to blocks act like they always were blocks: `[1].map &lambda{return "lambda"}` returns from the function. Is this a bug in JRuby?

Comment: `puts foo2` will return `foo2 (proc result is: proc) `

Answer (score 8):

Think of it this way: Proc.new just create a block of code that is part of the calling function. proc/lambda create an anonymous function that has special bindings. A little code examples will help:

```
def foo
  f = Proc.new { return "return from foo from inside Proc.new" }
  f.call # control leaves foo here
  return "return from foo" 
end
```

is equivalent to

```
def foo
  begin
    return "return from foo from inside begin/end" }
  end

  return "return from foo" 
end
```

so it is clear that the return will just return from the function 'foo'

in contrast:

```
def foo
  f = proc { return "return from foo from inside proc" }
  f.call # control stasy in foo here
  return "return from foo" 
end
```

is equivalent to (ignoring the bindings since not used in this example):

```
def unonymous_proc
  return "return from foo from inside proc"
end

def foo
  unonymous_proc()
  return "return from foo" 
end
```

Which is as clearly will not return from foo and continue to the next statement instead.

Comment: even though this is an old question, please do note that there is a difference between Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 where in the latter Kernel.proc behaves like Proc.new instead of as lambda.