# Why does calling a returning Proc, declared within a method, work?

Tags: ruby

I've been playing with the Codecademy Ruby course and there's an exercise on lambdas and Procs. I do understand the difference, but I don't quite see why the first code listing here works, while the second does not.

Why does this work:

```
def batman_ironman_proc
  p = Proc.new { return "Batman will win!" }
  p.call
  "Iron Man will win!"
end

puts batman_ironman_proc  # prints "Batman will win!"
```

But not this:

```
def batman_ironman_proc(p)
  p.call
  "Iron Man will win!"
end

p = Proc.new { return "Batman will win!" }
puts batman_ironman_proc(p)  # unexpected return
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435743/why-does-explicit-return-make-a-difference-in-a-proc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of how `proc` behaves with control flow keywords: `return`, `raise`, `break`, `redo`, `retry` and etc.

These keywords will jump from the scope where the `proc` is defined, otherwise the `lambda` has its own scope so those keywords will jump from `lambda's` scope.

In your second example the `proc` is defined in the scope of main. And as `tadman` commented below, you can't return from `main`, only `exit` available.

Your code will work if you switch from `proc` to `lambda`.

Comment: You can't `return` from main. You can only `exit`.

Comment: I found another explanation from the Oreilly Ruby book: "the `return` statement returns from the lexically enclosing method, even when the statement is contained within a block. [...] A proc is like a block, so if you call a proc that executes a return statement, it attempts to return from the method that encloses the block that was converted to the proc.