# LocalJumpError: unexpected return

Tags: ruby, lambda, closures, block, proc

I want to know why I cannot return from this block:

```
[1,2].each { |e| return e } # => LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

while these work:

```
[1,2].each { |e| Proc.new {return e} } # => [1, 2]
[1,2].each { |e| lambda {return e} } # => [1, 2]
```

Hope someone can explain.

Comment: Try out your code again but this time call the proc and the lambda (as the block also gets called). You'll see that the proc one will also raise. That's because blocks and procs are the same however lambdas act like methods. See http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/ or SO answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435743/why-does-explicit-return-make-a-difference-in-a-proc

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1402764/192702. It looks a little bit strange without an enumerator like `each`, but you can use the `next` keyword to exit any block.

Answer (score 3):

You can use return inside a block in Ruby. It will return from the enclosing method. In this case, there is no enclosing method, that's why there is an error, it's not because return in a block is illegal

Answer (score 0):

Open a ruby console (using `irb` or `rails console`) in a terminal and type `return 10`. It should give you the following error:

```
2.6.9 :020 > return 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):20
        1: from (irb):20:in `rescue in irb_binding'
LocalJumpError (unexpected return)
```

This is cause there's no enclosing method. To use `return` you must be returning from something.

When you use `return` in a Proc it is essentially like calling `return` from the most upstream context.

So if you execute your example in the console

```
[1,2].each { |e| return e }
```

it essentially doing the same thing as typing

```
return 1
return 2
```

in the console.

---

Your other examples don't actually execute what's in the nested proc / lambda which is why there is no error.

But if you call the proc it will throw the same error

```
[1,2].each { |e| Proc.new { return e }.call } # => LocalJumpError (unexpected return)
```

The lambda returns in the local context so there's no error

```
[1,2].each { |e| lambda { return e }.call } # => [1, 2]
```

---

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436030/1807586) has some more examples on using `return` within a proc or lambda